# copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 in the same workbook in excel

Tags: excel, function, copy

An excel sheet (sheet 1), gets updated on a daily basis by the Admin dept. I need to copy this data in sheet 1 to sheet 2 automatically in the same workbook.

Is this possible?

If so, pls help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In a vba macro you can run the following code

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A1")
```